# How do i integrate native sound in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

i am trying to integrate native sound in react native. I would appreciate if someone can help me. The code below is the NotificationModule.java file. When the panic alert push notifcation comes in when the user clicks on it. It navigates the user to this NotificationModule.java screen. what i want to do is that i want to integrate a native sound when ever the screen comes on.

```
package com.limestone.community;

import com.limestone.community.FullScreenActivity;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

public class NotificationModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    public static ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

    NotificationModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
        super(context);
        reactContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "NotificationModule";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void triggerFullScreenNotification(String title, String message, String channelId) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) reactContext
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        Intent fullScreenIntent = new Intent(reactContext, FullScreenActivity.class);

        fullScreenIntent.putExtra("title", title);
        fullScreenIntent.putExtra("message", message);

        PendingIntent fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(reactContext, 0,
                fullScreenIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(reactContext, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                .setContentTitle("Panic Alert")
                .setContentText("Immediate attention is required")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true);

        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
};
```

Comment: Do you want a sound when a notification arrives?

Comment: @Shivo'ham yes that is what i want.

Comment: Which plugin did you use?

Comment: @Shivo'ham we are building a native module for a fullscreen notification on a react-native application and we are using java to write the native module, so no plugin is used.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.limestone.community;

import com.limestone.community.FullScreenActivity;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

public class NotificationModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    public static ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

    NotificationModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
        super(context);
        reactContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "NotificationModule";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void triggerFullScreenNotification(String title, String message, String channelId) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) reactContext
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        // this is for playing a sound
        playNotificationSound();

        Intent fullScreenIntent = new Intent(reactContext, FullScreenActivity.class);

        fullScreenIntent.putExtra("title", title);
        fullScreenIntent.putExtra("message", message);

        PendingIntent fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(reactContext, 0,
                fullScreenIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(reactContext, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                .setContentTitle("Panic Alert")
                .setContentText("Immediate attention is required")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true);

        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

    private void playNotificationSound() {
        try {
            Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(reactContext, notification);
            r.play();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

As per the request, I modified your code using my justification.